# vb.net references to namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reference

I having quite the problem, I'm using NotePad++ for some obscure reasons to code in Vb.Net Asp.net and on my server I have a folder that I would like to add some .vb class and then in an aspx file, simply import the namespace and create an instance of these class... Should be easy, no?

Well, here is my architecture:

I have a file name default.aspx which contains :

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Geo" %>
<%
    Dim a As Access = New Access()
    Response.Write(a.hasAccess())
%>
```

and a class name Access in a subfolder named aspxcomponents

Here is the class access content :

```
Namespace Geo

    Public Class Access
        Function hasAccess() As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

And well, when I execute default.aspx I get the following error :

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'Access' is not defined.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Import Namespace="Geo" %>
Line 2:  <%
Line 3:  Dim a As Access = New Access()
Line 4:  Response.Write(a.hasAccess())
Line 5:  %>


Source File: C:\...\default.aspx    Line: 3


Show Detailed Compiler Output:


C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vbc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\17edf889\308e2904_d4a7cd01\obout_SuperForm.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\90a90acc\06f1d546_d4a7cd01\obout_ListBox.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\16815892\0259b030_d4a7cd01\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\db59a808\e25edd3b_d4a7cd01\obout_Flyout2_NET.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\1b343ee7\26831f32_d4a7cd01\obout_AJAXPage.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\04af17f9\ca3b7804_d4a7cd01\obout_Tree_DB_Net.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\2f6922c7\ba568500_d4a7cd01\obout_Show_Net.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\67fcad05\b8cabd41_d4a7cd01\obout_ImageZoom_NET.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\e0bf0dd3\2ae92003_d4a7cd01\obout_Splitter2_Net.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\923ae5b1\e6b6b705_d4a7cd01\obout_Window_NET.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\284fee82\00968846_25e3c701\obout_ASPTreeView_2_NET.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\d8821591\e82de323_ab03ce01\Server.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\3047a6af\a0af073a_d4a7cd01\obout_ComboBox.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\766a113f\729f1038_d4a7cd01\obout_Calendar2_Net.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\49cf6573\9c28c516_d4a7cd01\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\3e1c6afb\ac61a245_d4a7cd01\obout_Interface.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\419549c8\ce7cf703_d4a7cd01\obout_TextMenu.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\4e2fd5b6\be9cf743_d4a7cd01\obout_Grid_NET.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\7c45df4e\1c65fb14_d4a7cd01\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\161a8730\ea77face_d5a7cd01\obout_FileUpload.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\b94efe06\e8d6b43b_d4a7cd01\obout_EasyMenu_Pro.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\526f4d83\f431a930_d4a7cd01\Obout.Ajax.UI.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\assembly\dl3\7043b70c\48142501_d4a7cd01\obout_SlideMenu3_Pro_NET.DLL" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\App_Web_9j7lk7lp.dll" /D:DEBUG=1 /debug+ /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\" /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Specialized,System.Configuration,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\App_Web_9j7lk7lp.0.vb" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\App_Web_9j7lk7lp.1.vb"


Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 8.0.50727.5420
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 2.0.50727.5472
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\...\default.aspx(3) : error BC30002: Type 'Access' is not defined.

Dim a As Access = New Access()
         ~~~~~~               
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84e1764c\a7c5af94\App_Web_9j7lk7lp.0.vb(15) : warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Geo' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Imports Geo
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

ANY! help would be GREATLY! appreciated... I'm quite desperate :S

Everything I try doesn't work -.-

Thank you

**I made some test and it seems even if file Access.vb is not valid (replaced namespace with namejdacosijdfspace) I don't get any errors..**

...
Seriously, anyone? I'm really desperate :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues.

First, the class is public, but the function is unmodified. That means the function is private (or maybe protected/friend, depending on context). You need this:

```
Namespace Geo

    Public Class Access
        Public Function hasAccess() As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

Second, you imported the namespace, but didn't tell the framework where the code lives for that namespace. Try putting the .vb file in the special [App_Code folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx#sectionToggle1). Or, you could build the file into a *.dll as part of a class library and then put it in the special /bin folder.

Comment: App_Code folder is not an option for me because it every modification I do on it affect all the developers and we are working on the same distant server... As for the function, it never get to create an instance of the class, so I really don't beleive this is the problem. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @Hipny It *will* be a problem once you are able to create the class instance. And if you want this to work, you'll have to use App_Code. **There is no way to get ASP.Net to automatically compile and include code outside of that folder**

Comment: I take that back. You can set up a code-behind relationship, but that won't work for you here, either. And you could try including that in the code for your own control. But really: go app_code

Comment: That is what I did, I include the src of all a class with code-behind and in this file I have multiple classes -.-

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your import statement to [Imports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx).

The correct syntax is:

```
Imports Geo
```

As an alternative, you can remove the Import statement and fully qualify the Access class:

```
Dim a As Geo.Access = New Geo.Access()
```

Comment: Nope, cant do, the code of default.asp is append in a sub of a class by IIS, so Imports in a sub doesn't really works :S

Comment: Just added an alternate approach to solving the problem.

Comment: Tried it a thousand times :  error BC30002: Type 'Geo.Access' is not defined.

Comment: Is your Access class actually included in your project? That's just about the only reason it shouldn't be working.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how my project is defined since it was not created using visual studio